# up script in ovpn configuration file for Open VPN gives fatal error: could not execute external program

Tags: bash, scripts, vpn, iptables, openvpn

My openvpn finishes with the following:

```
Sun Sep 30 01:35:11 2018 masquerade.sh tun0 1500 1552 192.168.255.6 192.168.255.5 init
Sun Sep 30 01:35:11 2018 WARNING: Failed running command (--up/--down): could not execute external program
Sun Sep 30 01:35:11 2018 Exiting due to fatal error
```

This is `masquerade.sh`:

```
#Enable ipv4 forwarding

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

#Add a masquerade for outbound traffic on tun0:

sudo iptables -t nat -A  POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE

#Save the iptables rule.

sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"
```

Here's the conf file:

```
script-security 2
up masquerade.sh
```

I tried without `sudo` and it also won't work.I also tried `masquerade.sh`'s full path. What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: What user is OpenVPN running as?  Do you have `sudo` configured to work without asking for a password for that user?

Comment: @chicks im running openvpn as sudo because it requires it. I don't have sudo configured to work without asking for password

Comment: If you don't have a `user` defined in your config then OpenVPN will run as `root` and the script doesn't need to `sudo` again.  The `sysctl` only needs to be done once so I'd put it in `rc.local` or your script that starts openvpn.  I don't think either of those is your problem though.  I'd put `touch /tmp/it_ran` at the top of the script to see if it is getting executed at all.  If the `/tmp/it_ran` script never shows up then you know the problem is before the script is getting run.